# Is there a best or recommended practice for naming Entity Framework migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, naming-conventions

When using Entity Framework code first migrations is there a best practice for choosing a name for each migration?  For example each name might contain a version number or the change(s) made to the model or both.

```
Add-Migration Added Manager.Employees
Add-Migration Add_Employee_ManagerId
Add-Migration version 2
Add-Migration v2_Add_Employee_ManagerId
```

Any tips for selecting a good naming strategy for a project with multiple developers and many migrations?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712297/naming-conventions-for-code-first-migrations) but no answers.

Comment: When you add a new migration, a class is generated. The name of migration will be the name of the class (or at least part of it). The answer to this question may vary according to the user's opinion

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean, Fabio.  When I use add-migration, I provide a name for the migration.  I'm looking for advice on a naming strategy for these migrations.  For example, if I add the column managerId to the employee table.

Comment: A migration may have a lot of the new columns and new entities... it is hard to give a name that describe all the changes. However, I try to follow a pattern, like "Products", "ProductsFix", "CustomersAndUsers"

Comment: Good point. I suppose something similar to a repository commit.  Would be nice if along with a name you could provide a short description.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the Microsoft docs it states:

> The migration **name** can be used like a commit message in a version control system. For example, if I made changes to save customer reviews of products, I might choose something like AddProductReviews.

So by their provided example of `AddProductReviews` I'm thinking that [Upper Camel Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) is what Microsoft recommends.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/

Comment: That's the strategy I ultimately settled on. Good to see that MS agrees and has now documented it.

Comment: What if your migration has multiple changes to many tables. For example if changes were to both the Products and ProductReviews tables? How would you go about naming these kinds of migration that encompass many changes?

Comment: @Andrew What our team does is name the migration as the **intent** at which it was created - that way you don't have crazy names. `AddProductReviews` (as above) may cover many tables.

Comment: In the link there's no mention of any suggested practice any more. The quote is gone, so is the example. It wasn't much of a *recommended* practice anyway.

Comment: @GertArnold - `dotnet ef migrations add AddBlogCreatedTimestamp` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: And "we give migrations a descriptive name". Is that "recommended practice" or just common sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is opinionated answer but I think worth sharing,

To avoid confusion with your other classes I personally prefer _snake_case with leading underscore.

migration will contain 3-4 part (can be repeated for multiple times for different changes)

```
_entiy__type_of_change__colunm__extra_info
```

1. `_product_added_oldprice_updated_name_maxlenth`
2. `_customer_deleted_ispremiume`

this way when you search, you can ignore all items starting (can also configuration ide to ignore in search)